# Disallow month view in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date picker for date selection for check in check out date, Here I dont want the user to click on the month view as shown below:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Change the Date selection , directly , maybe if you fork the date-picker from github , and change it your needs you could get it , else as far as i have knowledge you cannot change it , But an alternate way would be to use ajax , or other readily available options that allow you to do so . You can check the documentation at http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#inputs

Another way around would be 
1) You can use the startDate and endDate options of bootstrap datepicker.

2) Set today's date in startDate

var today = new Date();

3) To get last date of the month use this approach

```
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Finally

```
var today = new Date(); //Get today's date
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);  //To get the last date of today's month
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    startDate: today,
    endDate: lastDate
});
```